# Langevin equation vs. Volterra integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

What is the difference between a **Volterra integro-differential equation** and a **Langevin equation** (with an integral damping term)? Both seem to be of the same form.

It appears to me that the former is used in a mathematical context, whereas the latter comes from physics. Is that true?